# Short proof of the principle of explosion in propositional calculus

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I am working through 'Notes on logic and set theory' by P.T. Johnstone. Exercise 2.2 reads

> Write down a proof of ($\bot\Rightarrow q$) in the propositional calculus.

Here $q$ is an arbitrary primitive proposition and 'proof' means deduction from the axioms

> (a) $(p \Rightarrow (q\Rightarrow p))$
>
> (b) $((p \Rightarrow (q\Rightarrow r)) \Rightarrow ((p \Rightarrow q) \Rightarrow (p \Rightarrow r)))$
>
> (c) $(\neg\neg p \Rightarrow p)$

and modus ponens. Here is my solution:

> Instead of proving that $\,\,\vdash (\bot \Rightarrow q)$ we prove that $\{\bot\}\vdash q$. This is easy:
>
> > 1. $\bot$ ----- premiss
> > 2. $(\bot \Rightarrow ((q\Rightarrow \bot)\Rightarrow \bot))$ ----- instance of (a)
> > 3. $((q\Rightarrow \bot) \Rightarrow \bot)$----- modus ponens
> > 4. $(((q\Rightarrow \bot )\Rightarrow \bot) \Rightarrow q)$ ----- instance of (c)
> > 5. $q$ ----- modus ponens
>
> Then the Deduction theorem finishes the job. (The Deduction theorem says that if $S$ is a set of propositions and $s,t$ are propositions then $S\vdash (s\Rightarrow t)$ if and only if $S\cup \{s\}\vdash t$.)

I am unsatisfied, however, since I did not explicitly write down the proof of $(\bot \Rightarrow q)$. I tried to do this by following the algorithm given in the proof of the Deduction theorem (see Theorem 2.4 in Johnstone's book) but it turned into a mess, so I gave up. My question:

> Is there a short proof of $\,\,\vdash (\bot \Rightarrow q)$, like that of $\{\bot\}\vdash q$?

Comment: Following the algorithm given in the proof of the deduction theorem gives you a proof that's exactly 17 lines long, doesn't it? (3 lines for each instance of an axiom or modus ponens, and 5 lines for the proof of $\bot\to \bot$ at the beginning.) If 17 lines doesn't qualify as short, what does? Most formal proofs in a Hilbert system like the one you've written down will be many many lines long.

Comment: @AlexKruckman Your comment encouraged me to try again, and I managed to write down the 17 lines. I'd still be interested in a shorter proof of this basic fact.

Comment: Note that a few exercises later, Johnstone asks for a proof of $p\land q$ from $\{p,q\}$. This is also a very basic fact, but the result is apparently such a mess that Johnstone labels the exercise "for masochists only". The moral is: no one should ever actually write down proofs in Hilbert systems.

Comment: You are right. I just finished with that other exercise and though the proof is also 17 lines long, the lines are much longer! I didn't realize how long proofs of simple facts in Hilbert systems could be.

Comment: Here is a 21 line proof (slightly different axioms, but same idea) of   $\neg \neg P \to P$: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3661388/proving-vdash-neg-neg-p-to-p-double-negation-elimination-in-first-order/3661726#3661726 So yeah, no short proofs, even for the simplest of results, in these kinds of systems.

Comment: @Bram28 Expanded out, (¬¬p⇒p) and converting to Polish notation becomes CCCp00p (I mean part of it looks like... makes it easy to remember).  That's a special case of the more general CCCpq0p (which can get interpreted as: if you negate a conditional, then the antecedent is true).  Given CCCpq0p, one can prove C0p in a *single* detachment!

Comment: @AlexKruckman CCCC0p00C0p is an instance of CCCpq0p with p substituted with C0p, and q with 0.  CCC0p00 is an instance of CCCpq0p, with p substituted with 0, and q with p.  C0p is consequence of CCCC0p00C0p and CCC0p00 by detachment.  End of proof.  I had 352 characters left.

Comment: @DougSpoonwood the only thing more miserable than using a Hilbert system is reading Polish notation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To save us from parenthesis hell, let's follow the proof-theory convention of writing $P \rightarrow (Q \rightarrow R)$ as $P \rightarrow Q \rightarrow R$.

We can write down a short, seven-line proof as follows:

1. $\neg\neg x \rightarrow x$ [axiom C]
2. $(\neg\neg x \rightarrow x) \rightarrow \bot \rightarrow (\neg\neg x \rightarrow x)$ [axiom A]
3. $\bot \rightarrow \neg\neg x \rightarrow x$ [MP 2,3]
4. $(\bot \rightarrow \neg\neg x \rightarrow x) \rightarrow (\bot \rightarrow \neg\neg x) \rightarrow \bot \rightarrow x$ [axiom B]
5. $(\bot \rightarrow \neg\neg x) \rightarrow \bot \rightarrow x$ [MP 3,4]
6. $\bot \rightarrow \neg\neg x$ [axiom A]
7. $\bot \rightarrow x$ [MP 6,5]

How can one find this proof? I first inspected your proof, which uses the deduction theorem, and took note of the key step: $\bot \rightarrow \neg\neg x$ constitutes instance of axiom A. I knew that one can get $(\bot \rightarrow \neg\neg x) \rightarrow \bot \rightarrow x$ cheaply from $\neg\neg x \rightarrow x$ using a standard trick coming from the proof of the deduction theorem: I use this trick with some frequency, see e.g. [another Hilbert system question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4567579/axiomatic-derivation-of-conditional-from-biconditional/4569638#4569638). This is where the first four lines come from.

This is certainly an improvement over the 17 lines obtained by naive use of the deduction theorem. I don't know whether one can get anything even shorter.

Comment: If instead of having CCCp00p as an axiom, we use the more general 1 CCCpq0p as an axiom, if my memory serves me correctly, under condensed detachment, C0p follows as D1.1.  I found it as suggested using Prover9 just playing with those axioms one day.  In other words, there's some most general unifier of two instances CCpq0 and CCCab0a, where CCpq0 is a theorem.  Figuring the substitutions out once again, one instance of CCCpq0p is CCCC0p00C0p, another is CCC0q00, so C0p follows in one detachment.

Comment: @DougSpoonwood Ok, I struggled through the Polish notation, and I understand your proof. But the OP does *not* have $(((p\to q)\to \bot)\to p$ as an axiom, so I don't see the relevance of your comment. In the particular system the OP asked about, I don't think you're going to do better than Z.A.K.'s 7-line proof.

Comment: @AlexKruckman Axioms most often used for classical logic are the most general tautologies for their bracket type.  (((p→⊥)→⊥)→p) is not a most general tautology for it's bracket type.  It's a special case of (((p→q)→⊥)→p).  (((p→⊥)→⊥)→p) can get obtained from another tautology purely by substitution.  There are no other tautologies from which (((p→q)→⊥)→p) can get obtained purely by substitution.  Like usual, there are no other tautologies from which a) and b) can get obtained purely by substitution.